# How do I get the value of an entire HTML dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I need to get the value of an entire  element and all its child  elements, so that I can create a duplicate of the element. Is there any way to do this with plain js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<select id="select">
<option>Bulldog</option>
<option>Pitbull</option>
</select>
<!--The entire dropdown with all its child option elements should be duplicated into the div element:-->
<div id="div"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think better to give the value for each options,

and maybe this js can help u

with HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<select id="select">
<option value="Bulldog">Bulldog</option>
<option value="Pitbull">Pitbull</option>
</select>
<!--The entire dropdown with all its child option elements should be duplicated into the div element:-->
<div id="div"></div>
</html>
```

and with JS :

```
var j = document.getElementById("select");
var i;
var value = "List Value: ";
for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        value = value + "\n" + j.options[i].text;
    }
    
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cloneNode:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('#select').cloneNode(true));
```

it clones the element then append the clone to the page body. you don't need to get the element's value.

hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This code below shows you the result by cloning the element as a whole and appending to the the element id="div". Let me know if this is what you needed.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="select">
      <option>Bulldog</option>
      <option>Pitbull</option>
    </select>
    <!--The entire dropdown with all its child option elements should be duplicated into the div element:-->
    <div id="div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  var x = document.querySelector("#select").cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("div").appendChild(x);
</script>
```